# Problem generating an interactive Rmarkdown report within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, download, r-markdown, document

I'm trying to generate an interactive Rmarkdown report within a shiny app and I'm having some issues regarding the renderization of the shiny widgets. The problem is that widgets are do not render when the call to the report is done. Everything else is shown, but not the shiny elements.

My problem arises when the Rmakdown file contains shiny elements. I have a shiny app which contains a button that calls a render to a Rmakdown file, but it's a file containing shiny widgets, so the output is the Rmakdown file perfectly rendered, but with no shiny elemnts appearing.

There's a simple version of what I'm trying to solve.

Here is the shiny app.

```
        ui <- fluidPage(
      column(2,
             fluidRow(h4("PD")),
             fluidRow(hr()),
             plotOutput("pd_value")),
      column(2,
             downloadButton("report", "Download File"))

    )

    shinyServer(function(input, output)
{

  #Grafico PD
  output$pd_value = renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    #filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {

      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      params <- list(PD = c(1000,5))
      print(params)

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file)
    }
  )


})
```

And here's the Rmarkdown report.

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
### Client recap.
After load the data, the user can get a recap of the most useful information for the client at a glance.

```{r}
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    column(2,
         fluidRow(h4("PD")),
         fluidRow(hr()),
         plotOutput("pd_value"))
  ), 

  server = function(input, output) {
#Grafico PD
  output$pd_value = renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
  })
  },

  options = list(height = 300)
)

```
### Client recap.
After load the data, the user can get a recap of the most useful information for the client at a glance. In this box the user gets the following:
````

If I run the report it works well. If I run the app it works well too. But when I call the render report from the download button of the app, it does not render correctly.

Could you give me any suggestions?

Thank you so much.